# Website doesn't update when accessed, unless page is refreshed

Tags: html, refresh

I have an HTML document that is on a local server (not a webserver, if that's important). Sometimes, after updating some files, I go to visit the HTML document and it is not updated. However, if I try to refresh the page, the content then updates.

I'm not sure why this is occurring considering that I am opening the page anyway after update, so it should have the latest values then.

Comment: Is there a way to internally clear the cache or update to the newest version then? My page is dynamic, so the data will keep changing.

Comment: It also could be server caching

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that browser is caching the HTML document it self. It is fine for static pages, where data remains constant

but as you stated that content of the page is dynamic, you can do 2 things

1. Add expiration header for document via server side code. This ensures that when ever user tries to access your page, the browser always sends a request to server and ignores local cache. Some of the headers you need to set

   > Cache-Control **:** no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
   >   Expires **:** -1
   >   Pragma **:** no-cache
2. Add expiration via meta tags

   > <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Fri,31 Dec 2010 11:59:59 GMT" />
   >   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">

   This should be kept under <head> tag

Comment: Hm, tried that but it still doesn't seem to work. I think it's specific to jQuery because the main design of the site works, such as the CSS. However, when I enter the url manually, both jQuery (the getJSON() method), and jQuery UI (for a slider) stop functioning, so I believe it has to do with that. Is there something different that the browser does when refreshing vs. manually entering the URL?